# Trim spaces from lines of a file in Powershell

Tags: file, powershell, trim

I am trying to read out a textfile in Powershell, store the lines in a variable and then trim it. (It's a file, which I want to use later for setting permissions with icacls.) The textfile looks like this:

```
  PATH        USERID                  ACCESS   ACTION  TREE   CHANGE
D:\test   Administrators               FULL    GRANT    YES     NO      
D:\test   mydomain\domain-admins       FULL    GRANT    YES     NO      
D:\test   mydomain\user1               READ    GRANT    YES     NO      
D:\test   mydomain\user2               CHANGE  GRANT    YES     NO
```

My code so far looks like this:

```
$string=(get-content .\accesses.txt) | foreach {$_.Trim()}
```

I also tried it like this:

```
$str=(get-content .\accesses.txt)
$str[0].Trim()
```

None of these commands work, the line looks just the same. It's just spaces in the textfile, but trim won't work.

Comment: `Trim` will only remove leading and trailing whitespaces, so I can't see what difference should be made except for on the first line. What are you actually *trying* to do?

Comment: What should the resultant file look like?

Comment: Where are you getting the file from? Is it possible to have the file exported as CSV instead?

Comment: You want to read the file as a CSV? Here you go: `((gc infile.txt | out-string) -replace '[ \t]+', ' ').trim() | convertfrom-csv -delimiter ' '`

Comment: @AlexanderObersht Assuming it is tab delimited and that is what the op wants that is a good idea.

Comment: It captures spaces as well, hence the square brackets. SO codeblock doesn't show the space though. (

Comment: @AlexanderObersht Thanks that's what I was looking for! Maybe you could help me with this task too: How do I get just one entry like "Administrators" or "read" out of the file and store it in a variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "entry"? A line from the original file? `$foo = gc infile.txt | ? { $_ -match "[ \t]+Administrators[ \t]+" }`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$rows = @()
Get-Content $filename | ForEach-Object { $Line = $_.Split(' ').Trim() | `
    Where-Object { $_ -ne [String]::Empty }; $rows += @(,$Line)}
```

Each line will be split using `' '` then trimmed and returned as an array
so `'this is    a     string   '` would be returned as `@('this', 'is', 'a', 'string')` which you could then join with `','` for example.